# “Realistic” telepathy

Tags: science-based, telepathy

In my WIP series, there’s a symbol that causes the atoms composing your body to basically teleport in a loop, the result being that your mind can extend outside your body wherever/whenever you will it as long as the symbol is charged with electricity.

There’s an alien race that is born with this symbol on their brains (it’s active from birth to death, because of the nervous system constantly charging it with electricity).

What’s the least physics-defying explanation for the aliens’ ability to interface with both non-telepathic organics and machines (both of which are key to the plot)?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? You already have a scheme on how all of this works, do you want an explanation why it might work? Do you want to know how to extend it to machines? Do you worry in particular about the non-telepathic part for some reason? Btw, what do you mean by "teleport in a loop"? Could you explain exactly why you think teleporting "atoms" will accomplish what you want? Or is that the question? How much handwaving is ok for you?

Comment: I think it's reasonably plausible for an alien race to have developed a biological means to detect and transmit radio signals.

Comment: You're using magic ("there’s a symbol that causes the atoms composing your body to basically teleport in a loop") and mixing it with science-based which is never a good idea.  Adding the word "realistic" just confuses what you're trying to do even more.  "Physics-defying" makes this even more confusing as you're already defying-physics with the "sign" magic thingy.  This question is terribly unclear as to what you start from (magic or science ?) and what you want (reality or ... ?).

Comment: The most realistic explanation is that all of this takes place in a computer simulation.